# How to add 10 different css class to posts

Tags: css

How I can assign a different css class to each post of the 10 posts of each blog page?

Like this :

```
<li class="first-post">..
<li class="second-post">..
.
.
.
<li class="tenth-post">
--
Second page
--
<li class="first-post">..
<li class="second-post">..
..
```

So on !
Thank You a lot for the help.

Answer (score 3):

Use the function `post_class()` in your template:

```
<div <?php post_class(); ?>>
// your post content
</div>
```

Then add a counter to the post classes per filter on `post_class`:

```php
// functions.php
add_filter( 'post_class', function( Array $classes ) {

    static $number = 1;

    $classes[] = 'post-number-' . $number++;

    // reset the number
    if ( 11 === $number )
        $number = 1;

    return $classes;
});
```

You get a new class on each entry now that looks like `post-number-1`, `post-number-2` and so on.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but I want to make only 10 classes that they repeat. is there anyway to edit your function to make it happens.

Comment: @user3358086 See my update.

Answer (score 1):

A simple counter can also do this:

```
<?php $counter = 1; ?>
<?php //wp loop start ?>
<div class="css-class-<?php echo $counter ?>">
</div>
<?php $counter++; ?>
<?php //end wp loop ?>
```

If you want to use better css class naming, you can use an array:

```
<?php $class_name = array ( 'first-post', 'second-post', ........, 'tenth-post' );
$arrKey = 0; ?>
<?php //wp loop start ?>
<div class="css-class-<?php echo $class_name[$arrKey] ?>">
</div>
<?php $arrKey++; ?>
<?php //end wp loop ?>
```

Comment: Thank you @The sufi for this amazing code, I will try all. Thanks to everyone

Answer (score 0):

As what @toscho said, is perfect. You can also differentiate each of the blog post with their post ID like this:

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
...
</article>
```

There would be `#post-1` for the post where the post id is 1, and so on...

Comment: Thanks, it doesnt work because I want to give only 10 css classes that they repeat.. which means I costumize only 10 css in my style.css